# calculate amount_total from tax Odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo

Please I want to know how to calculate the tax and adding it in total amount . taxs name's is FODEC nad he has a fixed pourcentage 1% of total.
so : total= 1% of total + total .

please help me . I can't resolve it .

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, http
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class AccountTax(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.tax.template"

    fodec = fields.Boolean("FODEC")


class AccountTax(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.tax"

    fodec = fields.Boolean("FODEC")


class InvoiceStampTax(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move'

    
    fodec = fields.Many2one('account.tax',string="FODEC", domain=[('fodec', '=', True)])
```

here when I choose Fodec taxe 1% , he must calculate the total amount in second picture
[image]

[image: second picture]

Comment: Why do you implement it as extra and don't use already implemented features like extra taxes, fiscal positions, etc.?

Comment: Client demanded that . also I want to learn the principle and method of this task @CZoellner

Comment: **You can calculate the taxes by taxes = 
 tax_id.compute_all(price, currency_id, quanty)** after that taxed_amount = sum(t.get("amount", 0.0) for t in taxes.get('taxes', [ ]))